# Using custom factory HK2 DI with Jersey

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, hk2

I'm using the HK2 container in my Jersey application . I need to use my custom factory method to get the injected instance from the HK2 container. 
For example ,

```
// Here I declare the IOC binding.
public class ApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Logger.class).to(ILogger.class).in(Singleton.class);;       
        bind(MySqlRepository.class).to(IRepository.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}



 public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public static ApplicationBinder binder ;
    public MyApplication () {
        binder = new ApplicationBinder();
        register(binder);
        packages(true, "com.myapplication.server");
    }
    }
```

Here is my code :

```
public class BusinessLogic

    {
        //@Inject
        //ILogger logger ; 

        //Instead 
        ILogger logger = DependencyResolver .resolve(ILogger.class) // resolve will get ILogger from HK2   container
    }
```

The reason I need to do this way is for sometimes , I allocate classes manually which has dependencies , so in this way each use of @Inject return null.
For example, if I use new BusinessLogic() , then the logger with @Inject is null. I have to bind businesslogic also and use IOC in order to get the ILogge.

I need something like this:

```
public class DependencyResolver {    

    public static <T> T resolve(Class<T> beanClass){           
        return instance;
    }    
}
```

I need to use the DependencyResolver  in order to get the instances I registered in MyApplication.

Any suggestions.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you tried to build a org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory for your needs?

Comment: I did , but I need to take the bind configuration I made in the ResourceConfig with the ApplicationBinder .

Comment: Please provide some more informations aka code. What exactly did you tried to inject ILogger into your Repository? How is Repository involved - is it bind somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what exactly you want to do, but ...

I think you misunderstood `AbstractBinder.bind(...)` or bindings itself. Also, afaig you can't inject something into an instance which is not kinda managed component (like your `BusinessLogic`).

See [jersey.java.net - ioc](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/ioc.html) for examples regarding your `BusinessLogic`. You may have a look at `ComponentProvider` and/or `InjectableProvider`

For your ILogger I would suggest to create and bind a Factory like this:

```java
public class LoggerFactory implements Factory<ILogger> {

    // inject stuff here if you need (just an useless example)
    @Inject
    public LoggerFactory(final UriInfo uriInfo) {
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public ILogger provide() {
        // here you resolve you ilogger
        return MyLocator.resolve(ILogger.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(ILogger instance) {
        // ignore
    }

}
```

Bind Factory

```
public class ApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindFactory(LoggerFactory.class).to(ILogger.class).in(PerLookup.class /* or other scopeAnnotation if needed */);

        // what's you Logger.class ? 
        // bind(Logger.class).to(ILogger.class).in(Singleton.class);      
        // bind(MySqlRepository.class).to(IRepository.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

Hope this was helpful somehow. Maybe someone is willing to write something about Providers for your case.

Comment: Thanks allot , "something into an instance which is not kinda managed component (like your BusinessLogic)." , I think its very helpful to let me inject a service managed by IOC into my BusinessLogic , like using the ILogger , so here I can't use the annotation Inject and I need other option to get the ILogger there . Hope I'm clear.